# Can someone text a photo to someone unsolicited?

Tags: spam

I am being told that “all the new work phones for the security staff” are having issues with spam calls by my SO. I can buy that no problem, but this... He got a text message from a woman who said he chatted with her using a different first name(?) and that’s something that’s happening to entrap people? I don’t know. Am I being gaslit, or are there cases where this happens where photos get texted with messages that are targeted to either solicit funds or action?

The photo was of a woman lifting her shirt. I am being told that this is an unknown woman who was never contacted previously by my SO and sent an unsolicited photo to his work phone asking to talk after a chat that he says didn’t happen and he’s telling me about so I don’t think something is happening when it’s not.

Comment: What or who is the subject of the photo?

Comment: You're not being gaslit in any case; that's a very specific term with a very specific meaning which doesn't apply here. Quite possibly being lied to and/or blackmailed, though.

Comment: The amount of people coming here, asking questions about the fidelity of their significant other is disturbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your title question without going into the scenario in particular: yes, absolutely. MMS (the multi-media extension to SMS) can be sent from any phone with a service that supports them, to any number; what the receiving number does with it is up to their service, hardware (virtually all mobile phones in use today support MMS but most land-lines don't), and software.

On compatible hardware and with MMS included in the service plan, most phone messaging software will download and display MMS (including images) from anybody. No "solicitation" is required; the recipient doesn't even need to approve receiving the message (though they could choose not to view the message, or even to delete it, of course). It's possible in theory to automatically ignore SMS or MMS from unknown numbers, but in practice it's uncommon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply about technical possibilities. I appreciate it. That’s exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can use the up arrow (to the left of the answer) to mark the answer as helpful, and the checkmark to say it answered your question.